# Vue2 and unit tests : SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: testing, import, vuejs2, module, syntax-error

I am doing unit tests with vue-utils on the front-end of an application written in vue2.

When I run my test, I get this error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
(I don't even need the problematic module in my test.)

I have looked at several answers on the subject (including adding "type": "module" in package.json or add extension ".mjs") but I always get an additional error after testing the solution.
I work with node/14.19.2.

Do you have any idea?
I don't know which file to show you, don't hesitate to ask me for my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue by adding this line:

```js
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!module_name)']
```

in my `jest.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and in my case the Visual Studio added (modules/js file). Check the top of your vue/javascript code, is there any imported file or not!

Comment: It wasn't the issue but thanks for your answer!